# Vertical line graphs in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to draw vertical line graph (like the first graph on [this](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/book7/bk7i18/bk7_18i1.htm) page):

[image]

The deal is I have about ~15k data points whose frequencies (along Y axis) I want to present. I also want to be able to to present the frequencies in different colors : for example for the 1st 5k points, I want yellow colored line graphs for the next 5k I want red etc.

How can I do this in R? Pointers to packages (and to helpful source code where possible) will be very useful. Beginner in R here.

Thank you.

Comment: How many categories do these points occur in?  How are the points numbered?

Comment: The plot on the page you point to has 10 vertical lines.  You want to do that with 15k lines?  A typical display is <2000 pixels wide.

Comment: @Michael : Well it's simply $X$ number of points that have some frequencies associated with them. I have 3 categories. Karl : yes, so the lines will be very close to each other and it will seem like the oscillation plots that you see.

Comment: @Karl : On more thinking, I think I get your point now. I will consider making plots for values that exceed a certain frequency threshold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `plot` function with `type="h"` to get the vertical lines and `col` to specify the colors, using `rep` to create the vector of colors that you want, as follows:

```
# simulate some data
x <- runif(15000)
x[sample(15000, 50)] <- runif(50, 0, 5)

# make the plot
plot(x, type="h", col=rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), each=5000))
```

This makes the following (yellow looked terrible):

[image]

Comment: (+1): I should have waited for clarification from the OP.

Comment: Super. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use a barplot in combination with the grDevices-package to create a color-palette.

```
require(grDevices)

# data
dat <- sample(1:10,15000,prob=runif(10),replace=T)
dat <- sort(dat)
plotdat <- as.data.frame(table(dat))
plotdat[,2] <- plotdat[,2]/sum(plotdat[,2])

# generate colors
colors <- heat.colors(10)
# and sort them according to frequency
colors <- colors[order(order(plotdat[,2],decreasing=T))]
barplot(plotdat[,2],names.arg=as.character(1:10),col=colors)
```

This creates a plot with the property "the higher the color-heat, the higher the frequency"

[image]

Comment: This looks good. Except that I want contiguous blocks of red, followed by contiguous blocks of yellow etc.

Comment: @user721975 I ordered the colors. If you skip this step, the color increases from left to right. Another option is to provide a vector of colors (vector-length=number of bars to plot) by using rep().